# Error Upgrade Magento 1.6 to 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, error, upgrade, magento-1.6

I upgraded Magento from my Magento 1.6 to 1.9 last night, and it's going error 500 Server Internal Error then my magento can't be opened.
so what i'm do is chance user permissions of `index.html` on root folder to 644 and `index.html` on downloader to the same permissions and delete all file n folder in Magento cache, but it can't chance anymore.
and i'm wanna to trying access the admin panel and cannot be shown and error likes this

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '`group`' in
>   'where clause', query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `m2epro_config` AS
>   `main_table` WHERE (`group` = '/wizard/') AND (`key` =
>   'status')

please help me to fix it out..

Comment: you directy upgrade your magento in live or local?

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is pretty self-explanatory. It means there is no column called `group`.

If  M2EPro 6.3.6 is not compatible, upgrade to 6.3.8. The backticks are a "feature" that has been disallowed in Magento with the SUPEE-6788 patch due to the security issues arising from previously allowing them.